# Proof by construction of Wiener's tauberian theorem on $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis

Would anyone have a reference to a proof by construction of Wiener's tauberian theorem in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

As a reminder the theorem goes as follows:

> **Theorem ([Rudin, Functional Analysis Th. 9.5](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=Sh_vAAAAMAAJ&hl=en))**: Suppose $K \in L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and $Y$ is the smallest closed translation-invariant subspace of $L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ that contains $K$. Then $Y = L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ if and only if $\hat{K}(t) \neq 0$ for every $t \in \mathbb{R}^n$ (where $\hat{K}$ is the Fourier transform of $K$).

More generally, I am looking for a decomposition of a function $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ as linear combination of translations of $K$.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: What do you mean by a "proof by construction" here? What do you find unsatisfactory about the proof Rudin gives?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick reply Patrick. By 'proof by construction' I mean an explicit representation of $f$ as a limit in $L^1$ of linear combinations of translations of $K$, where the coefficients can be written down explicitly as a function of $f$ and translations of $K$. As I mentioned in the second part of the question, I am more interested in finding such a linear combination, than proving that it exists.